# Screen is black; Mouse cursor doesn't move

Tags: xubuntu

So I turned on the laptop awhile ago and noticed that the "Ubuntu" start up is kinda stretched.

Usually, the wallpaper will appear as you get to type the password right? But the wallpaper ain't there.

So fast forward, the screen is black and the mouse cursor doesn't move no matter how hard I try to move it. Also, the folder icon turned to an icon which looks like a blank paper.

Moreover, the sidebar only shows the thumbnail for Libre Office and the others have no thumbnails at all.

Something popped up and said that it is because of an internal error blabla.

How do I fix this? I don't want to lose my files :( Help!

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PRINT</kbd> and type (while holding) <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>. This will restart your machine.